# Integral of square of variable in expression in square root in denominator

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble with following integral

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}} dy
$$

that according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281%2B4*x%5E2%2B4*y%5E2%29+dy) is
$$
\frac{1}{2} \ln( \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} + 2y) + c
$$

which I can verify but I can't figure out what substitution to apply or what functions to use for integration by parts in original integral. What would be your first step to attack this integral please? Thank you.

Comment: Standard substitution for the form $a^2+ x^2$ is $x = a tan\theta$.  That works here and gets you to $\int sec\theta\; d\theta$.

Comment: set $$\sqrt{4y^2+4x^2+1}=2y+t$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thank you, I've tried this but I can't get rid of y with this substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, the standard formula $$\color{red}{\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\ln(x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2})+c}$$ For derivation, let $x=a\tan \theta \implies dx=a\sec^2\theta d\theta $ $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\int\frac{a\sec^2 \theta d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2+(a\tan\theta)^2}}=$$ $$=\int\frac{\sec^2 \theta d\theta}{\sec\theta}=\int\sec\theta d\theta=\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)+c$$  $$=\ln(\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}+\tan\theta)+c$$ Now, substituting the value of $\tan \theta=\frac{x}{a}$ $$=\ln(x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2})+c$$

In the given integration, $x $ is treated as a constant. Now we have  $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}} dy $$ $$ =\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+4x^2)+(2y)^2}} dy $$ Let, $2y=t \implies 2dy=dt\ or\ dy=\frac{dt}{2}$ $$ =\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1+4x^2)+t^2}}+c$$ $$ =\frac{1}{2}\ln(t+\sqrt{(1+4x^2)+t^2})+c $$  $$ =\frac{1}{2}\ln(2y+\sqrt{(1+4x^2)+(2y)^2})+c$$  $$ =\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}+2y)+c $$

Comment: Thank you! Very clear. I couldn't find this standard formula anywhere but I can verify it holds =).

Comment: Alright, Can I add its derivation  at the top of answer?

Comment: I think that would be great.

Comment: You may see the derivation of the standard formula in the edited answer

Comment: Thank you! And thank you @lulu. Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer yet.

Comment: Nicely done.  +1!